# IJCADのARXのビルドでエラー

Tags: ijcad

お世話になります。IJCADのGRXを使って開発しています。
IJCADでプロット出力の機能を使い、プレビューのイメージをPNGファイルに出力するプログラムを作成しています。ビルドをすると

エラー 13 error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl GcPlPlotInfoValidator::setMediaMatchingPolicy(enum GcPlPlotInfoValidator::MatchingPolicy)"　（長いので以下省略）

といったエラーが大量に出力されるのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

拝見したところ、GcPl系のクラスでエラーが生じているようです。この場合「gplt.lib」をリンクに加えると解決すると思われます。具体的には以下のいずれかで対策してみてください。

1.Visual Studioでプロジェクトのプロパティから「リンカー」→「入力」→「追加の依存ファイル」に「gplt.lib」を追記する

2.ソースコード中に以下の一文を加える。
    #pragma comment(lib, "gplt.lib")